# How to set imghash value to search for the best match?

Tags: javascript, image, hash, discord.js

I m using imghash to make a discord bot (npm i imghash) I found a very small error that it read image perfectly. But there is a small problem. Let imagine if the hash id is d780a1b1a9838393 and i saved hash id of that image d780a1b1a9838392 then it will not provide the response. I hashed to many images and use that for detective game in our server. Best part is that bot the images is same just a bit diff. that the quality. I want the imghash to find for the best match if the hash id did not match 100% then bot will still response with an additional text that maybe or something i set.
THIS IS MY CODE I M USING TO MAKE RESPONSE

````js
      let url = message.attachments.first().url

        request(url, async function(err, res, body) {
           if (err !== null) return;

          imghash
            .hash(body)
            .then(hash => {
            let result = db[hash];

            if (result == undefined) {
              embed 
                   .setTitle('New Pokemon')
                   .setDescription(`Hash ID: **${hash}** [message link](${message.url})`)
                   .setImage(url)
                   client.channels.get('691155351575199825').send(embed)
                  client.channels.get('687233915974320148').send(url + ' ' + hash + " " + message.url)
                    return message.channel.send("There is an error you maybe using `image address` rather than that use `Link Address`. This error may have any of these problems: \n1) You are using screenshots rather than URL. Which will not work righ now. So use a URL. \n2) You are using URL but its the image adress. Actually image address reduce the quality of image so use link address.");
            } message.reply(result)
            console.log("[" + message.guild.name + "/#" + message.channel.name + "] " + " " + message.author.tag + " " + result + " " + hash);
          })
        })``` if you think i need to improve something for that then what changes should i made?
````

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Is the hash `d780a1b1a9838393` or `d780a1b1a9838392` ? What do you mean by "it will not provide the response" ? Does it hang or do you have an error ? Also, if I understand correctly, you want to return the image with the closest hash ? The hash result of 2 very similar strings can and will difer greatly Are you sure hashing is the right solution here ?

Comment: The error is the quality of the image if the quality decreases then hash id changed by one letter and do not get any response. I just want it to answer the closest value if the hash didn't match exactly.